# How to Concatenate strings into fixed length in sql

Tags: sql

Can someone please help me in the below question regarding concatenating string for a fixed length.

In the below code inline "`vv_string = concat(vv_string,"|", trim(Facilitydisp))`" I need to check the vv_string value to the max to 65535 while concatenating only and then reset it once the length is reached.

```
head d2.seq
         vv_string = ""
      detail
          if(ocr.facility_cd = 0)
              vv_string = "ALL FACILITIES SELECTED"  
          elseif(vv_string > "")
             vv_string = concat(vv_string,"|",trim(Facilitydisp))           

            else
              vv_string = trim(FacilityDisp)
```

Comment: Please format your codes properly

Comment: I don't see any SQL in your question. Which programming language is that?